# Cannot find module 'webpage' when using PhantomJS in MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs

I'm using the `phantom` npm package via `meteorhacks:npm` package. However when running the basic Phantomjs example under Meteor.js I'm getting the `Cannot find 'webpage'` error.

Why is this happening?

**Code**

```
var phantomjs = Meteor.npmRequire('phantom')
var page = Npm.require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
    console.log('Page Loaded');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

**Error**

```
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/Users/username/Code/phantomtest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:129:18)
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/phantom.js:8:16
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/phantom.js:26:3
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/username/Code/phantomtest/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150305-02:16:51.629(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150305-02:16:51.630(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/username/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.41.1f49rvw++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

**packages.json**

```
{
    "phantom": "0.7.2"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*webpage* is a PhantomJS module not an NPM package. PhantomJS and node.js have a different runtime and this is why you need to use a bridge like the phantom package. [`phantom`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) itself will provide a reference to `page`:

```
var phantom = Meteor.npmRequire('phantom')
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open("http://github.com/", function (status) {
      console.log('Page Loaded');
      ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

Keep in mind that scripts written for the bridge will have to be written [different](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details) from plain PhantomJS scripts.

Comment: Note that this syntax is wrong now, since the phantom module was completely ported to a Promise syntax.

Comment: What is the correct syntax now? I am receiving a similar issue because I am trying to require webpage in a script that's executed by the ghostdriver. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: The new syntax can be found at https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node